# Integer to int using jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

I have a weird situation where the getter in a class returns a primitive int type, and the setter takes a Integer class.

When jaxb unmarshals an element to this class, it cannot find the setter it is looking for:

```
public class Foo {
    int bar;

    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Integer bar) {
        this.bar = bar.intValue();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding:

```
@XmlElement ( type = java.lang.Integer.class, name = "bar" )
```

to the getter (and the setter), to change the type of the field in schema, but that does not help.

During unmarshalling I get this error: The property has a getter "public int com.example.getBar()" but no setter. For unmarshalling, please define setters.

I can't modify the class, as in, I can't change bar to an Integer or add a new setter with primitive type, but I can add annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this issue by configuring JAXB to use field access.  This is done via the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation:

```
package forum8334195;

import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {
    int bar;

    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Integer bar) {
        this.bar = bar.intValue();
    }

    /**
     * Put logic to update domain object based on bar field here.  This method
     * will be called after the Foo object has been built from XML.
     */
    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
         System.out.println(bar);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: good point, though that will skip setBar() all together. We have some business logic in the setter that needs to be executed.

Comment: @prmatta - Is this business logic something that you could do in an XmlAdapter or afterUnmarshal event.

Comment: possibly - how would an XMLAdapter help here?

Comment: @prmatta - It depends on what you want to do.  Does your setter act just on the value being set or does it affect the state of the domain object somehow?

Comment: it affects the state of the object.

Comment: @prmatta - I have updated my answer with an `afterUnmarshal` event that you could leverage to updated your `Foo` object based on the value of the `bar` field.

Answer (score 3):

Posting from phone so bear with me!
The property doesn't match the javabeans spec so that's the problem, as you probably know. Can you add a new setter/getter pair using a new name, which both use Integer, and put the XML tags on that new property? The new methods would just delegate to the existing ones. HTH

Answer (score 0):

It's a real shame you can't introduce any extra methods. If you could add an extra *private* method, you could do this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Foo {
    int bar;

    public int getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    @XmlElement
    private Integer getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Integer bar) {
        this.bar = bar.intValue();
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you're probably stuck using [`@XmlJavaTypeAdaptor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) and [`XmlAdaptor<Foo, YourAdaptedFoo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html), but that's *really nasty*.